# Name for this rhetorical device

Tags: phrase-requests, rhetorical-devices, simile

> The text: "The court determined that Student B exhibited adverse educational impact because notwithstanding her passing grades, during her final year at School #1, her symptoms were sufficiently severe that she was unable to attend public high school at all and required homebound instruction."
>
> My analysis: The distortion is in the word "passing." Student B was actually earning all A's and B's. But the author of "the text" finds it expedient to call the grades "passing" because elsewhere in her document she argues that Student A did not experience a significant academic decline when he went from a 3.8 gpa to a 2.2. So she harps on the fact that although Student A's grades have been declining, he is still passing his courses... and therefore should be found ineligible for special education.

A helpful ELU participant proposed the following description of what's going on:

> When a fact is presented as representative of the truth, even though it clearly omits key details.

**What is this rhetorical device called?**

**Bonus question**: I also need an effective idiom or simile which describes this form of bias or slant.

Comment: Iit all sounds like a big misunderstanding.

Comment: @Josh - It might look like that from the outside.  It is massively Machiavellian, however.

Comment: Perhaps "Lying by omission" or a "smoke screen". You may also have a look to [Rhetoric Devices and Fallacies](http://www.flashcardmachine.com/rhetoric-devices-andfallacies.html).

Comment: This is a kind of intentional understatement. The typical label baked in rhetoric for intentional understatement is *meiosis*, and its near synonym *litotes*. I wouldn't use *litotes* for this example, however, as that that device is employed ironically, sarcastically. By contrast, *meiosis* is more neutral on motivation.

Comment: It's a violation of the Gricean maxim of quantity ('truthfully' saying that you can see a cat in the garden when you can actually see 10, and you're not in a logic class). The misrepresented 'quantity' here is the quantity / measure of marks / grades being (mis)represented. Obscurantism ('the practice of deliberately preventing the facts or **full details** of something from becoming known' – [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obscurantism)).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yay Edwin to the rescue!  You gave me two technical descriptions AND a wonderful simile.  Muah!  Please make it an answer.

Comment: I think people are misunderstanding 'not withstanding'. (or I am ).  I read the 'text' as completely agreeing that the student's studies were hurt, and describes how(severe symptoms etc).  The "not withstanding" part was purposely recognizing and actively overruling the argument that 'passing was good enough'.  The Text isn't implying that passing was the same as A's and Bs.. quite the opposite.

Comment: @Tom22 - If you want to read the legal decision I boiled down here in one little paragraph, tell me, and I'll post the links.  Then you can see for yourself that Student B earned A's in general, but when her health deteriorated, she earned a mix of A's and B's.  It really bothers me to see her grades described as "passing."

Comment: @aparente001 ok I re-read your comments and I see you were commenting about "elsewhere in the text".  I'll put aside my preoccupation about what "not withstanding" would mean to me as isolated.  I agree that is sounds like an unfair situation and ruling.

Comment: @Tom22 - Glad that worked.  I've been staring at this stuff so much, sometimes I get very confused. // From her point of view, "notwithstanding" worked fine -- because in her distorted worldview (that of a special education lawyer specializing in representing school districts and fighting parents), it's perfectly all right to play fast ans loose with the facts -- as long as she wins.  I forgot to say, she sees students as either "passing" or "failing."

Answer (score 3):

This involves a willful violation of the Gricean maxim of quantity (eg 'truthfully' saying that you can see a cat in the garden when you can actually see 10, and you're not in a logic class). The misrepresented 'quantity' here is the quantity / measure of marks / grades being (mis)represented.

The intent to mislead by (for instance) using ambiguous phraseology is termed
**obscurantism**

> the practice of deliberately preventing the facts **or full details**
>   of something from becoming known.
>   {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obscurantism)} (bolding mine)

.......

> 2. deliberate obscurity or evasion of clarity. {[RHKWebster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscurantism)}

Answer (score 2):

With all due respect to the Gricean maxim of quantity (as Edwin Ashworth so nobly sets it forth), I think what you are really looking for is [**damning with faint praise**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damning_with_faint_praise).

> Damning with faint praise is an English idiom for words that effectively condemn by seeming to offer praise which is too moderate or marginal to be considered praise at all. In other words, this phrase identifies the act of expressing a compliment so feeble that it amounts to no compliment at all, or even implies a kind of condemnation.

This term is quite common, and it is the one you'll hear everywhere but inside of logic classes.

Comment: Hurray for ELU!  This is also very good.  Do you have an example or simile for me, or shall I stick with Edwin's cats?

Comment: You can express gratitude by voting the answers up that you find helpful.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry.  I've been trying to fit as much of this material into my document as I can.  Right now I have almost all of it in, but it's a bit too much and some bits will have to come out.  I wish I could accept them both answers.  However, I can certainly upvote them both now.